# When the Headphone button press generates KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE in android API > 21?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the keyCodes for handling ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON Intent. I am working on API > 21, Below is my code. Every time I press the headset button I receive keyCode=KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK. Can someone please let me know when will I be receiving KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE or KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT or any other keyCode related to MEDIA.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    final MediaSession session = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), "TRIGGER");
    session.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    session.setActive(true);
    PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
                            PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_FROM_MEDIA_ID | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE |
                            PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
            .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, 1, 2, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
            .build();
    session.setPlaybackState(state);


    session.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(final Intent mediaButtonIntent) {

            String intentAction = mediaButtonIntent.getAction();

            if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction))
            {
                KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)mediaButtonIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (event != null)
                {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    int code = event.getKeyCode();
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.i("TRIGGER", "EVENT RECEIVED");
                        Log.i("TRIGGER", String.valueOf(event));
                        Log.i("TRIGGER", String.valueOf(action));
                        Log.i("TRIGGER", String.valueOf(code));
                    }
                }

            }
           return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
        }


    });

}
```

Intent filter is also been mentioned as below in the manifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
```

LogCat details when I press the headset button.

```
09-11 17:39:42.134  15765-15789/com.example.amit.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-11 17:39:42.147  15765-15789/com.example.amit.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-11 17:39:46.843  15765-15765/com.example.amit.myapplication I/TRIGGER﹕ EVENT RECEIVED
09-11 17:39:46.843  15765-15765/com.example.amit.myapplication I/TRIGGER﹕ KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK, scanCode=226, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=217783805, downTime=217783641, deviceId=4, source=0x101 }
09-11 17:39:46.843  15765-15765/com.example.amit.myapplication I/TRIGGER﹕ 0
09-11 17:39:46.843  15765-15765/com.example.amit.myapplication I/TRIGGER﹕ 79
```

Comment: You'll get those events when you press those buttons or are you saying you are and they don't work?

Comment: I have only one button on my headset. As I have experienced with other music player that button being  used for playing, pause or forwarding the sound track, I expect that button to generate the keyCode of ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY or anything related to media. But when I press that button it only generates keyCode as KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK. Is there a way further to check the expected keyCode?

Comment: How is it used for a those things? Hold it down long time or double tap etc?

Comment: Holding for some time will open google voice search in my mobile. I'll check for double tap and let you know by tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not saying to try those things. Just asking how you have been using it in the other apps. How do those apps know you mean pause and not skip track when you press it?

Comment: I just gave an example of a music app guessing that it might be using similar keyCodes. This is my first try here.

Comment: You said you can use one button for multiple things, so I just wanted to know more details of that experience. That will give a clue to what they are doing.

Comment: No, I didn't use. :) I just mentioned a example.